# Android Studio 3.0.1 crashes repeatedly

Tags: android-studio, crash

I have used Android Studio for some time. I last updated it to version 3 and used it last about a month ago with no serious issues. After about about a month absence I ran it to edit an app. It would then suddenly disappear as if I had not being running at all.I would then run it again and just as suddenly it would disappear again. When I say disappear, I mean literally disappear as if it never existed on screen.

These disappearances or crashes would happen randomly:

- I could open Android Studio and then leave the room for a while and on returning, it is no longer running. It has disappeared!
- I could be busy coding and suddenly it disappears!
- I could be coding for a while and then select Run to install and run the app on my phone and suddenly Android Studio would disappear

There does not seem to be any pattern or specific trigger that causes it to crash (disappear). Also, when I restart it, there is no indication that there was a problem.

I have downloaded and reinstalled the latest version and the problem persists.

I can access the log files but have absolutely no idea how to interpret them.

Any help would be appreciated. It's driving me nuts.

Comment: I have the same problem anyone have solution?

Answer (score 0):

Finally tracked down the problem. Uninstalled Git and Android Studio is working perfectly once again.I will try and reinstall Git sometime later and see if I can get the two to work together again (as they did before).

Comment: Uninstalling Git from Windows didn't do it for me.

Comment: @FractalBob after uninstalling, did you also set version control to none in Android Studio settings?

Comment: No, I didn't. But won't that disable Local History?